# Concatenation in R with rbind without formatting output

Tags: r

Is there a way to concatenate "without" formating numbers ?

```
> pos.ord
Gb19a Gb19b Gb24a Gb24b Gb28a Gb28b Gb11a Gb11b
378   386   246   248   360   372   162   261
380   386   246   248   360   372   187   261

> table.error.means
   Gb19a    Gb19b    Gb24a    Gb24b    Gb28a    Gb28b    Gb11a    Gb11b 
2.380952 2.380952 7.539683 7.539683 5.952381 5.158730 5.952381 5.158730

> rbind(pos.ord, table.error.means)
```

rbind format numbers so the output is now... :

```
Gb19a      Gb19b      Gb24a      Gb24b     Gb28a      Gb28b
378.000000 386.000000 246.000000 248.000000 360.00000 372.000000
380.000000 386.000000 246.000000 248.000000 360.00000 372.000000
2.380952   7.539683   7.539683   5.952381   5.15873   5.952381
```

Can I get this kind of concatenation so R doesn't do additional formatting ?

Comment: Nevermind, R doesn't export zeros after coma...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns in a data.frame are vectors. The elements in a vector are (must be) of the same type, for example `numeric()` or `integer()`. It seems you are trying to bind a data.frame of `integer()`s with a data.frame of `numeric()`s. R has no choice but coerce (convert) your `integer()`s into `numeric()`s, the reason why you now see ".000000".

I don't think there is much you can do unless you are ok changing the way you store your results. You could for example work with transposed versions of your data.frames, then use `cbind()` instead of `rbind()`. This way, each column (your previous rows) can keep its own data type:

```
pos.ord <- t(pos.ord)
table.error.means <- t(table.error.means)
cbind(pos.ord, table.error.means)
```